# RabbitMQ high availability with Spring AMQP

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to configure a RabbitMQ cluster in Spring, so I followed the Spring AMQP docs (http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html), but I get an error when adding addresses:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" addresses="host1,host2" />
```

The dependencies I defined in gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.amqp', name: 'spring-amqp', version:'1.2.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.amqp', name: 'spring-rabbit', version:'1.2.0.RELEASE'
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?
Thanks!

Edit:
The error I get is:
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'addresses' is not allowed to appear in element 'rabbit:connection-factory'.
host1 & host2 are IPs of virtual machines.

Comment: You have to be more specific. What kind of errors do you get and how host1, host2 is defined?

Comment: Are you missing the port number? The documentation you link to has port 5672 specified but it is not present in your addresses attribute.

Comment: No, the issue is the "addresses" attribute itself, I edited my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you declared spring-rabbit XSD file in `schemaLocation` for version 1.0. Just change:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd

to

http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.2.xsd

to match your spring-rabbit version, and it should work.